# Advanced Custom Field - Extract multiple value of Relationship field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm using the "Adavanced Custom Field" WordPress plugin for the creation of relational fields. I created a custom post type "CPT 1" and added it as a relational field in the user card. The goal is to assign one or more CPT 1 terms to users.Inside the archive page of the custom post type I want to show the terms of the relational field of the current user.

I can't extract the terms within an archive page. I need it inside an archive page and in other page templates, as I have to perform a series of checks (IF in PHP).

The code I used is the following:

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$custom_field = get_field_object('custom_field_client', 'user_'. $user_id );

echo $custom_field;
```

I should extract an array of values. How can I solve?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)?

There is an example that could work:

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('custom_field_client', 'user_'. $user_id );
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

        // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span>A custom field from this post: <?php the_field( 'field_name' ); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I Cray, thank you for the support. I replied above to your comment